# Improving and publishing an application. Need some advice

Tags: c++, projects

Last term (August - December 2008) me and some class mates wrote an application in C++. Nothing spectacular, it is an ORM for Sqlite3. We implemented some stuff like reflection to make it work and release the end user from the ugly stuff. Personally, i think we made a nice job, and that our ORM could actually be useful for someone (even though its writen specifically for Sqlite3, its easily adaptable for oter databases).

Consequently, i`ve come to the conclusion that it should be published somewhere (sourceforge most likely) as an open source project. But, as it was a term project, there are some things that need to be addresesed before doing that. Namely, it has some memory leaks that should be fixed, and some parts of the code could be refactored to make everyone´s life easier in the future.

I would like to know more experienced C++ programmers opinion on some issues:

- Is it worth rewriting some parts to
  apply new techonologies (for example,
  boost).
- Should our ORM be adapted to latest
  C++ standard? Is there any benefit in
  doing this?
- How will we know when our code is
  ready for release?
- What are the chances that this ORM
  will be forgotten into the mists of
  the internet? (i.e is it worth
  publishing it beyond personal pride
  as a programmer?)

Right now i can`t think of many more questions, but i would like to read on similar experiences.

EDIT: I should probably translate my code + comments to english right? (self question)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I guess I am "more experienced" with regard to your particular question.  I co-developed an open source web application language & template system a lot like ColdFusion back in the early days of web design before Java or ASP were around.  You can still see it at http://www.steelblue.com/ if you are interested.  It's still used at the company I was at when it was developed, but I don't think anywhere else.

What I found is that unless you are already well connected and people are watching what you are doing, getting people to use your open source code is just about as hard as selling somone your closed source program.  You really need to advocate for your project and it should have some kind of unique selling proposition that distinguishes it from the compitition.

So, that's the unsolicited advice.  Here are some specific answers to the questions you had...all purely my opinion, of course.

I wouldn't rewrite any code unless you have a featuer you want to put in.  That feature might be compatibility with a specific platforms or compilers.  It might be to support a new db datatype or smarter indicies or whatever.  If you are going to put some more serious work into the applicaiton, think about a roadmap of what you can realistically accomplish in the next iteration and what choices will make the app the "most better" at the end of your cycle.

Release the code as soon as it is usable for a specific purpose, any purpose.  Two reasons.  First off, there might be someone who wants it for that purpose right now.  If it's not available, they will use something else.  Also, if it's open source, they might contribute back to the project.  Second, the sooner you find out how much people want to use the code, the better.  Either it will be more popular than you expect and you can get excited about continuing the development....or....you will find that no one is even visiting your web page to see what you've got.  In either case, better to know sooner than later what people really want from your project so you can take that into account when planning new releases.

About the "forgotten into the mists."  I think most projects are.  I don't want to be a downer, but looking at Wikipedia, there were 5 C++ ORM tools popular enough to get mention and they were all open source.  As I said above, unless you can sell your idea to people, they are going to go with another proven open source solution.  For someone to choose you over them, three things have to happen:  1.  They need a feature you have that the others don't.  2. They find your project web site and it demonstrates the superiority of your code.  3. They trust your code enough to give it a shot.

On the other hand, if you are in this for the long haul and want to continue development thigns get easier over time.  Eventually the project will get all the basics covered and you can start developing those new featuers that aren't in the other solutions.  Also, the longer you are in active development the more trustworthy the project will seem. Finally, you will get more experience in the nitch.  2 years from now you will be better positioned to say where your effort will have the most impact on bettering the project.

A final thought:  If you are enjoying it, learning from it, and it's not getting in the way of you keeping food on the table, it's a good use of your time.

Good luck!
-Al

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the open source part:

If you really want to make it an open source project, you really should publish it regardless of it's current state - fully working and debugged - or half working and full of memory leaks.
Just, if it's state is bad, make sure to document it, and give it a suitable version number (less than one?). then others may view your code, suggest improving, join your team, etc...

Answer (score 1):

My--rather random--thoughts on the matter (in the order I think is most important):

- How will we know when our code is ready for release?

Like [Liran Orevi said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/795975/improving-and-publishing-an-application-need-some-advice/807321#807321): if you're going open source release early. Document it reasonable well, and take the time to provide a road map of planned or hoped for future improvements (these are a invitation for people to help you, so note which ones have no one working on them).

- Is it worth rewriting some parts to apply new technologies (for example, boost).
- Should our ORM be adapted to latest C++ standard? Is there any benefit in doing this?

SQLite relies on a fairly limited base. Maybe you don't want your tool to demand a much heavier environment. If the code in not currently a tangled and unmaintainable mess, you might want to avoid boost and newest frills. Once you have a stable release (1.0 at least) you can starting thinking about the improvements that can be made for version 2.

- What are the chances that this ORM will be forgotten into the mists of the internet? (i.e is it worth publishing it beyond personal pride as a programmer?)

Most things end up in the big /dev/null in the sky, and there is only one way to find out... If it goes anywhere at all, you win. If it doesn't it was a modest investment, and maybe you learned something while you were at it.